# Where to get name of signature algorithm from SSLSocket?

Tags: python, ssl, digital-signature, x509, verification

I could not find a suitable way to get the name of the signature algorithm used for a certificate that is received by an SSLSocket. I'm aware you can pull the bytes of the peer's cert with `SSLSocket.getpeercert(True)` but I don't know what to do with it past that. PyOpenSSL doesn't seem to have an easy interface to load an X509 from it's byte content.

I would like to know this information as certificates with SHA1 are not allowed to have expiration times after January 1st, 2017 and this is not checked by Python's `SSLSocket.do_handshake()` implementation.

Comment: You might use the cryptography library instead. This one provides [signature_hash_algorithm](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/reference/#cryptography.x509.Certificate.signature_hash_algorithm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the very helpful comment pointing me in the right direction, you can use the `cryptography` module to load the DER X509 format that the `SSLSocket.getpeercert()` function outputs.  From this `Certificate` instance you can also access many other fields about the certificate such as expiration time. Here is the way that I am doing it right now:

```
import cryptography.x509
import cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl
import ssl
sock = ssl.SSLSocket()

# Wrap a socket, connect, handshake, etc etc...

cert = cryptography.x509.load_der_x509_certificate(
    sock.getpeercert(True),
    cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend
)
print(cert.signature_hash_algorithm.name) # This prints "sha1".
```